# how to apply styling on the parent container of a:visited?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to style my divs(that're parent container of links) differently when the links have been visited. Can I do that using pure CSS, or I need to resort to JS ?

Comment: You probably can't do this with JavaScript either. Browsers will not allow you to know which links the user might have previously visited, you'd have to track them and store that information in a cookie or `localStorage`, which is not exactly `:visited`

Comment: do you mean that this jquery  statement: `$('a:visited').parent('div').css('color: #fff;');` wont work ?

Comment: Of course not. Sizzle (the selector engine that jQuery uses) only approximates CSS selectors. It does not and cannot emulate most of the pseudo-elements and classes which CSS has, like `:first-letter`, `::selection` or `:hover`. Have a look at the list of selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: And I might add that if browsers did allow this information to leak out it would present a security threat: http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Comment: so this means... I cannot in anyway use the browser facility to remember & style up the containers of visited links differently..!? :(

Comment: Like I said, you can track which links your users visits when using your site in a cookie and style those differently using JavaScript

Comment: ohkk... got it. Thanks a lot for showing the path !

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this using pure CSS, not even in the latest CSS3 specification. You can do it with JS. With plain JS its quite unpleasant thing to do. If you use let's say jQuery, then you can do something like this:

```
$('a:visited').parent('div').css('color: #fff;');
```

Comment: This will not work. `:visited` is not implemented by jQuery (or more specifically, Sizzle)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do backreferences like this in CSS. You'll need to select them using JavaScript.

Alternately, HTML5 allows you to put <a> elements *around* block elements so you can turn this inside out:

```
a:visited .parent_container { background: pink; }
```

Comment: What do you mean "a elements around block elements" - then the a element would become the parent of the block element and obviously this guy want's to style their parent, not their content (which is easy).

Comment: @Veseliq I'm suggesting to change the HTML markup: put the link around the whole block, so you can access ".parent_container" as a child of the link. Of course, this depends on the situation, but it wouldn't need JS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using only **CSS**.
You've to implement your `:visited` logic.

Then using JS, when the user click on a link, add a class (*ie* `visited`) to its parent div.